# Create a redirect link to an another page using primefaces, spring

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

I want to create a redirect link to an another page using primefaces, spring:

```
if (true condition) {
     //redirect to page
} else {
     //keep the current page
     //open dialog
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you're using spring mvc controllers ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if( true condition ) {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.sendRedirect("www.google.pl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition is true) {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect("other-page.xhtml");
}
else {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("myDialog.show();"); //assuming you have set the widgetVar on your dialog to "myDialog"
}
```